# On "als es ihr die Höflichkeit einem vornehmen Manne gegenüber... erlaubte" from Die Prinzessin von Cleve

Tags: relative-pronoun

The question is on *es* as highlighted in this excerpt from Die Prinzessin von Cleve (see [full text](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/die-prinzessin-von-cleve-7452/2)) by Madame de La Fayette.

> Am Morgen nach ihrer Ankunft ging sie aus, um sich Geschmeide bei einem Italiener auszusuchen, der für jedermann einen Handel damit trieb. Dieser Mann war mit der Königin aus Florenz gekommen und hatte sich dermaßen an seinem Handel bereichert, daß sein Haus eher dem eines Edelmannes als dem eines Kaufmannes glich. Als sie da nun weilte, kam der Prinz von Cleve dorthin und ward derart von ihrer Schönheit hingerissen, daß er seine Überraschung nicht zu bergen vermochte. Mademoiselle de Chartres konnte ein Rotwerden nicht meistern, wie sie die Bewunderung sah, zu der sie ihn hingerissen hatte. Nichtsdestoweniger bezeigte sie den Handlungen des Prinzen dem Anscheine nach keine andere Aufmerksamkeit, als **es** ihr die Höflichkeit einem vornehmen Manne gegenüber, wie er einer zu sein schien, erlaubte.

The French original goes like this ([full text](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/La_Princesse_de_Cl%C3%A8ves,_%C3%A9dition_Lepetit,_1820/Premi%C3%A8re_partie)).

> Le lendemain qu’elle fut arrivée, elle alla pour assortir des pierreries chez un italien qui en trafiquait par tout le monde. Cet homme était venu de Florence avec la reine, et s’était tellement enrichi dans son trafic, que sa maison paraissait plutôt celle d’un grand seigneur que d’un marchand. Comme elle y était, le prince de Clèves y arriva : il fut tellement surpris de sa beauté, qu’il ne put cacher sa surprise ; et mademoiselle de Chartres ne put s’empêcher de rougir en voyant l’étonnement qu’elle lui avait donné ; elle se remit néanmoins, sans témoigner d’autre attention aux actions de ce prince que **celle** que la civilité lui devait donner pour un homme tel qu’il paraissait.

An English translation (from [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:ThePrincessofCleves.djvu/20) and [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:ThePrincessofCleves.djvu/21)) goes like this though it is not very helpful for the purposes of this question.

> The day after her arrival, she went to choose some jewels at a famous Italian's; this man came from Florence with the queen, and had acquired such immense riches by his trade, that his house seemed rather fit for a prince than a merchant; while she was there, the prince of Cleves came in, and was so touched with her beauty, that he could not dissemble his surprise, nor could Mademoiselle de Chartres forbear blushing upon observing the astonishment he was in; nevertheless, she recollected herself, without taking any further notice of him than she was obliged to do in civility to a person of his seeming rank

**QUESTION**

1. Does *es* correspond to *celle* (as highlighted above)?
2. If yes to 1, would *die, die* or *die, welche* be the more usual thing to expect in its place, giving us:

   > Nichtsdestoweniger bezeigte sie den Handlungen des Prinzen dem Anscheine nach keine andere Aufmerksamkeit, als **die, welche** ihr die Höflichkeit einem vornehmen Manne gegenüber, wie er einer zu sein schien, erlaubte
3. If yes to 1, please comment on whether *es* here is an aberration or conforms to an established usage.
4. If no to 1, how should I understand *es*?

**BACKGROUND**

The question is not about French, but only presumes some knowledge of French in someone who might be able to answer it.

I could have cast it purely as whether substituting *die, welche* for *es* is a good way to understand the sentence, but thought the French original would serve as helpful context.

Comment: my gutt feeling tells me that "die,die" is the right way to go, even though the sentence with "es" feals the most natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately my French is not good enough to answer your question in regards to that, but I hope I can still shed some light to help with the confusion.

The *es* is the direct object (akkusativ) to *erlauben*:

> etw. erlauben

means

> to allow smth.

---

If you simplify the sentence in question by leaving out the parenthesis and reorder it, you end up with the following to make it more clear:

> Die Höflichkeit erlaubt *es* ihr, Aufmerksamkeit zu schenken.
>
> The courtesy permits *it* to her, to show mindfulness.

It sounds rather convoluted in English. In both languages, you could also omit *es*:

> Die Höflichkeit erlaubt ihr, Aufmerksamkeit zu schenken.
>
> The courtesy permits her to show mindfulness.

Comment: Thanks. I believe we could also say that *es* refers to the clause just before *als*, or its 'idea' (after suitably removing *keine andere* from it).